# Overloadig + operator must take either no or single argument linklist

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, overloading

Set.h file contains in the public class :

```
 friend const Set operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b);
```

Set.cpp file contains a function called:

```
const Set Set::operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b)
```

Why is it this error appears: 'const Set Set::operator+(const Set&, const Set&)' must take either zero or one argument'

-edit-

As couple of you guys suggested , removing friend front my .h file lead to two more errors

Set.h:23:53: error: 'const Set Set::operator+(const Set&, const Set&)' must take either zero or one argument
    const Set operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b);

Set.cpp:73:55: error: 'const Set Set::operator+(const Set&, const Set&)' must take either zero or one argument
 const Set Set::operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b){

-edit 2 -

```
const Set operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b){
Node * intersection; 
while(a != nullptr && b != nullptr){
   if(a->value < b->value){
      intersection -> value = a;
      intersecioon = intersection->next;
      a=a->next;
   }
   if(a->value > b->value){
      intersection -> value = b;
      intersecioon = intersection->next;
      b=b->next;
   }
}
while(a != nullptr){
      intersection -> value = a;
      intersecioon = intersection->next;
      a=a->next;
}
while(b != nullptr){
      intersection -> value = b;
      intersecioon = intersection->next;
      b=b->next;
}
return intersection;
}
```

This is my operator function.

Comment: don't remove `friend`, remove `Set::` from the second line, i.e. in the `cpp` file, define it as `const Set operator+(const Set & a, const Set & b)`. If still have problems, post a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: many more errors, added function for more details

Answer (score 2):

According to the declaration in `Set.h`, `operator+` is a non-member friend function of `Set`. In `Set.cpp`, you are trying to define it as you would define a member function. The correct definition would have this signature:

```
const Set operator +(const Set & a, const Set & b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `Set::` from the definition in the `.cpp` file.

The header file is declaring `operator+` as a non-member function, so there's no reason for it to be prefixed by `Set::` in the declaration. That would be needed to define a member function of the class type `Set`.

Comment: @user3249265 Such as?

Comment: 'const Set operator+(const Set&, const Set&)':
Set.cpp:75:12: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'const Set' and 'std::nullptr_t')

Comment: @user3249265 That has nothing to do with the code you posted.